# Django: Safely check for related objects before deletion

Tags: python, django, model, race-condition

I have a Django app with two models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    baz = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

In a view, I want to delete a `Bar` object. Currently it's done with:

```
foo_to_delete = Foo.objects.get(pk=1)
if not foo_to_delete.bar_set.exists(): # step 1
    foo_to_delete.delete() # step 2
```

But now if at the time between the step 1 and the step 2, someone saves a new `Bar` object with the `foo` field pointing to `foo_to_delete` object, this new `Bar` object would be deleted by step 2.

Is there any way to avoid this, maybe by doing a single SQL call ? Does the Django ORM provides something for doing this kind of check before deletion safely ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem using `models.PROTECT`.

The models now looks like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    baz = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

And the view is like this:

```
foo_to_delete = Foo.objects.get(pk=1)
try:
    foo_to_delete.delete()
except models.ProtectedError:
    # show an error message
```

This seems to be mapped to only one SQL query, thus making it safe (I think).